# Is it possible to specify configuration variables or settings in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, triggers

This would be easy to do via a custom "settings" table, but wondering if there is something built in. If I want to specify persistent global settings or variables in an oracle database is there somewhere?

One case I am looking at is a db with auditing, and the triggers that keep the most recent nRecordsToKeep records history, but it seems like something that would be generic enough to be built in.

I would like to be able to configure this "nRecordsToKeep" globally, outside the trigger instead of having to change the trigger when this policy changes.

e.g. within the trigger after a shadow record is inserted there would be logic like (pseudo)

```
delete FROM (
  select * from audit_table order by create_date desc )
WHERE ROWNUM > GLOBALS.nRecordsToKeep
```

Anyone know of a way to add a persistent application level variable like this? (the approach by adding tables is outlined [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1578344046713) but it seems like there would be something more generically available.

Comment: AFAIK there's nothing in Oracle to specifically support the concept of application settings. I just create a table to store this kind of stuff.

Comment: You could define your global variables in a bodiless package but I'm not sure if you could access them in a query like in your example, and I can't actually test that right now.

Comment: Grand - not a biggie, maybe it's just me but it seems like it makes sense to me..

Comment: Yes, there is - look at sys contexts - http://www.dba-oracle.com/plsql/t_plsql_contexts.htm